# how vscode rust variable watch get type info?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust

I use vscode to debug rust, but in watch and variable window, all variable has no type info, only got value.

[image: rust variable watch]

However, for other tools like xcode c++, I can get both value and type.

[image]

Comment: I don't believe there is any setting to enable showing type information there. Either you have to infer it, or use the debug console to issue commands depending on your debugger (e.g. In LLDB, 'v' prints all variables for the current stack frame).

Comment: I find hover mouse on some filed, the type info will be showed.  or use lldb command frame variable -T  var_name